# Wordpress post page loop acting strange

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having an issue with my Wordpress post loop where if I add or update a post it decides to kill one odd and it disappears? Has any had this issue before?

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=4&cat=3'); while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?> 

    <div class="eventPostOuter">
        <div class="eventPost">
            <span class="eventsImage">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail( array(200,200) ); ?></span>               
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                        <span style="padding-bottom: 40px;" class="exerpt"><p><?php echo substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0,200); ?> [...]</p></span>
                            <!--<span class="excerpt" style="padding-top: 20px;"><p><a class="excerptLink" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read full article</a></p></span>-->



        </div>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

That is my code, perhaps I have made an error in there somewhere? I am unable to see what the issue is and it has only just begun doing it...

Comment: You do have it set to only display 4 posts at a time.

Comment: Not clear what your trying to say.Make it bit clear.So that i can help you out.

Comment: so the is being now that when I add or update and existing post one of them will vanish and it only shows 3. Also, If I change the featured image the image no loner displays...

Comment: Don't **ever** use `query_posts`. Change your query to use `WP_Query` which is the correct way. Also, set debug to true and check for errors

Comment: May I ask why to never use query_posts?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed the issue which is so strange, I changed the character limit from 200 to 180 and all of the posts show perfectly. :S